# SQL Bands - How to calculate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not quite sure what this type of query is, I thought perhaps a `CASE` statement or do I use `BETWEEN`? This is the data I have:

| SKU | QTY | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SKU-1 | 1 | 12.50 |
| SKU-1 | 5 | 11.00 |
| SKU-1 | 10 | 10.00 |
| SKU-1 | 15 | 8.50 |

It is basically what you would see on an ecommerce website when buying products. I want to fire in a qty & sku to this query (let's say 3), it would then know that 3 is between 1 and 5 and return me 37.50 or if a customer orders 12 it would return 120.00 etc.

As an update, this is how far I got:

```
DECLARE @sku nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @qty int
SET @sku = 'SKU-1'
SET @qty = 5
SELECT TOP 1 (price * @qty) FROM global_tier_pricing WHERE sku = @sku
```

This works until I send in a qty of 5, I would expect it to be (5*11)  and be 55.00 but it says 62.50

Comment: I don't see a query in your question

Comment: *" want to fire in a qty & sku to this query (let's say 3), it would then know that 3 is between 1 and 5 and return me 37.50"* What? How do you get `37.50` from `3`?

Comment: use the table that has the product base price , and let the where be `sku = xxx`  then the select  would be (select top 1 price * @quantity)

Comment: Please update to show your expected results as the verbiage you have is slightly confusing as "send in" and "fire in" are not really things that SQL does.  Perhaps you mean to provide parameters with those values?  Output will help a good deal here to add clarity please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can only have one price for a given sku and qty, you can filter for the right price in the `where` clause before the arithmetic

```
declare @qty int=3;
declare @sku varchar(100)='SKU-1';

select @qty * price
from your_table
where sku=@sku and qty=(select max(qty) from your_table where qty<=@qty)
```